# Remove class when scroll position is above first anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need some advice: I have a second navigation on my website that gets sticky as soon as it reaches the bottom of my top navigation. The second navigation contains different anchor links. When clicking on one anchor link the page scrolls to this appropriate section and marks the link with a different color and underline-style. Something like this:

```
+-------------------------------
| Navigation
+-------------------------------
| Second Navigation
+-------------------------------

Some content (different height)

+-------------------------------
| Anchor link 1
+-------------------------------

Some content (different height)

+-------------------------------
| Anchor link 2
+-------------------------------

...
```

This is the script I use to highlight (or to add a class for styling) the active links in this second navigation:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.secondary-nav-section').each(function (i) {
            var topPos = $(this).offset().top;
            if ((topPos - scrollPos) <= 182) {
                $('.secondary-nav-menu-item-active').removeClass('secondary-nav-menu-item-active')
                $('.secondary-nav-menu ul li').eq(i).addClass('secondary-nav-menu-item-active')
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Now to the problem: This code works fine as long as I scroll down and then up and down between the different divs with anchor links.

But as soon as I scroll further up as the first div with an anchor link my script does not remove the class `secondary-nav-menu-item-active` for the first menu link.

What code should I add to my script so the first menu item is only highlighted if the scroll position is "inside" the first anchor link section?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found a working solution. Maybe it helps someone else as well:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('.secondary-nav-menu-item-active').removeClass('secondary-nav-menu-item-active');
        $('.secondary-nav-section').each(function (i) {
            var topPos = $(this).offset().top;
            if ((topPos - scrollPos) <= 182) {
                $('.secondary-nav-menu-item-active').removeClass('secondary-nav-menu-item-active');
                $('.secondary-nav-menu ul li').eq(i).addClass('secondary-nav-menu-item-active');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

So, what was missing is this line of code:

```
$('.secondary-nav-menu-item-active').removeClass('secondary-nav-menu-item-active');
```

before adding the class to highlight the active second menu entry.